# MIN MAX using CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-statement

[image]

I have a table like this. All I want in country Name, Population number and if the population in MAX then label MAX and similarly for MIN. I have written below query in SQL Server using the `CASE` statement.

```
/* MIN/MAX Population amongst the countries */
SELECT 
    country, population,
    CASE
        WHEN population == MIN(population) THEN "MIN"
        WHEN population == MAX(population) THEN "MAX" ELSE "NA"
    END as "pop_stats"
FROM
    countries_by_population;
```

Comment: You should give us your sample data with the corresponding result as a text instead of an image

Answer (score 2):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32127b8220b9749892b4771a0141d88a)

**Firstly,** You should store  `@Min_Population` and `@Max_Population` by getting like below

```
DECLARE @Min_Population decimal(18,2), @Max_Population decimal(18,2)
SELECT @Min_Population = MIN(population), @Max_Population = MAX(population)
FROM countries_by_population
```

After that, you can compare the value for each item like (Note that character in SQL is closed in single quote instead of double one)

```
CASE
    WHEN population = @Min_Population THEN 'MIN'
    WHEN population = @Max_Population THEN 'MAX' ELSE 'NA'
END as pop_stats
```

**Full query**

```
DECLARE @Min_Population decimal(18,2), @Max_Population decimal(18,2)
SELECT @Min_Population = MIN(population), @Max_Population = MAX(population)
FROM countries_by_population

SELECT country, population,
    CASE
        WHEN population = @Min_Population THEN 'MIN'
        WHEN population = @Max_Population THEN 'MAX' ELSE 'NA'
    END as pop_stats
FROM countries_by_population;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @rushikesh maheshwari

Answer (score 0):

Use `over()` to make it a windowed function with no partitioning:

```
SELECT country, population,
    CASE
        WHEN population = MIN(population) over() THEN 'MIN'
        WHEN population = MAX(population) over() THEN 'MAX' 
        ELSE 'NA'
    END as pop_stats
FROM countries_by_population;
```

Comment: Your syntax has too many things incorrect. ex: **==** , **"MIN"** (double quotes), etc. Please check again

Comment: @Phong.  Corrected the '==' and the double quotes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window analytic function such as `DENSE_RANK()` including `ORDER BY population` clause in `descending` and `ascending` (default) orders to determine the `MIN` and `MAX` values through returning values as `1` from them, respectively, in order to be able to use within the `CASE` statement 
(*`DENSE_RANK()` function returns more than one row satisfying the related conditions in `ties` occuring cases among extremum values*)

```
SELECT country, population,
       CASE
         WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY population ) = 1 THEN 'MIN'
         WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY population DESC ) = 1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE 'NA'
       END AS "pop_stats"
  FROM countries_by_population
 ORDER BY population DESC
```

*Btw, do not use double quotes for derived column values, but use single quotes.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4b9770e4b0717ca90732383bc26c84cf)</kbd>